# C# interop startingslide not working

Tags: c#, powerpoint, winforms-interop

I want to start the presentation from a custom start index from parameter.
here is my code :

```
    public void Show(String filename, int firstslide)
    {
        try
        {
            _pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

            _presentations = _pptApp.Presentations;
            _presentation = _presentations.Open(filename, otrue, otrue, ofalse);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings sst1 = _presentation.SlideShowSettings;
            objSlides = _presentation.Slides;
            sst1.LoopUntilStopped = otrue;
            sst1.StartingSlide = firstslide;
            sst1.EndingSlide = objSlides.Count;
            sst1.ShowType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeKiosk;
            _oSlideShowWindow = sst1.Run();

            _oSlideShowView = _presentation.SlideShowWindow.View;

            IsShow = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

but, the presentation always shown slide 1 on first slide. Is there anyone know whats the problem with my code?